# Parenthesing error ora 00906

Tags: sql, oracle, project

```
CREATE TABLE AS_Film
  (
    ID_film            INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Opis               VARCHAR2 (25) NOT NULL ,
    Naziv              VARCHAR2 (25) NOT NULL ,
    Ocjena             VARCHAR2 (25) NOT NULL ,
    "2D_3D"            VARCHAR2 NOT NULL ,
    Sihronizacija      VARCHAR2 NOT NULL ,
    AS_Zanrovi_ID_zanr INTEGER NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE AS_Film ADD CHECK ( "2D_3D"       IN ('2D', '3D')) ;
ALTER TABLE AS_Film ADD CHECK ( Sihronizacija IN ('Da', 'Ne')) ;
ALTER TABLE AS_Film ADD CONSTRAINT AS_Film_PK PRIMARY KEY ( ID_film ) ;
```

Here what it is I try to upload ddl file to iacademyonline and upload rest tables fine but Films wont. Help me please.

Comment: Show the result you got and the expected result by you

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822) (emphasis mine):

> The VARCHAR2 datatype stores variable-length character strings. **When you create a table with a VARCHAR2 column, you specify a maximum string length (in bytes or characters)** between 1 and 4000 bytes for the VARCHAR2 column.

Here, you don't specify the length of your `VARCHAR2` columns `"2D_3D"` and `Sihronizacija`:

```
CREATE TABLE AS_Film
  (
    ID_film            INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Opis               VARCHAR2 (25) NOT NULL ,
    Naziv              VARCHAR2 (25) NOT NULL ,
    Ocjena             VARCHAR2 (25) NOT NULL ,
    "2D_3D"            VARCHAR2 NOT NULL ,       -- here
    Sihronizacija      VARCHAR2 NOT NULL ,       -- and here
    AS_Zanrovi_ID_zanr INTEGER NOT NULL
  ) ;
```

This will produce `ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis`.

Comment: Now is my mistake i must seperate add table and alter table :P

Comment: @Admir Glad to have helped you. *Depending you client*, maybe using `/` alone on it own line might allow you to send several SQL commands at once.

Comment: CREATE TABLE AS_Raspored
  (
    Vrijeme_datum   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
    AS_Film_ID_film INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    AS_Sala_ID_sale INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    AS_Film_ID_zanr INTEGER NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE AS_Raspored ADD CONSTRAINT AS_Raspored_PK PRIMARY KEY ( AS_Sala_ID_sale, Vrijeme_datum ) ;  i have  rroblem with  this i cant enter date allways says invalid month  what is format what should i change

Comment: @Admir As this appears to be a different issue, please don't use comments to request help. Instead, ask an other question. This is how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 3):

Columns "2D_3D" and Sihronizacija don't have length defined for the data type:

Update table definition to:

```
"2D_3D"            VARCHAR2(<length>) NOT NULL ,
Sihronizacija      VARCHAR2(<length>) NOT NULL ,
```

Comment: Now say ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: @AdmirŠehović, you realise that you have to replace the <length> with an actual number that fulfils your needs.

Comment: @AdmirŠehović, if this fixes your error then please set the other answer as official (accept Sylvain Leroux's answer) since it is more detailed and may be used for future reference!

Comment: Thanks a lot  for "invalid characters" its my mistake i should add  alter seperate ;)